# Cursor goes back to the beginning of line in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse 4.4.2 and I wrote the following code to get input from users：

```
System.out.print("y: ");
double y = scanner.nextDouble();
```

The program works. But the small problem is that the cursor on the console doesn't follow "y: " but shows up before it at the beginning of the line. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The text "y: " shows up 'too early' because you are printing it to the console before you read the double value using the scanner. Also, if you want to see what the user has typed, you have to first read the user input and then print it.

Change the code to this:

```
double y = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.print("y: " + y);
```

Comment: I want the user to see the prompt "y: " first and then type a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try `System.out.flush();` in between.